# Copy Pointer to Pointer and Copy Structure

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following Struct and Definition:

```
    typedef struct
{
    int nr; 
    char name[20]; 
} ART;


typedef struct List
{
    ART Art; /* Daten des Artikels */
                     // Zeiger auf nÃ¤chstes Listenelement
    struct List *next;
} LIST;

typedef LIST *pointList;

pointList pHead = NULL;
```

I create an struct of ART. Then I want to create a function to create a List with many structs of ART.

```
ART art;
scanf_s("%d", %art.nr);
scanf_s("%s", art.name, (int)sizeof(art.name) - 1);


LIST new;
new.Art = art;

if(pHead)
memcpy(&new.naechstes, &pHead, sizeof(LIST)); //Think its not the right one?


pointList newList = &new;


    memcpy(&pHead, &newList, sizeof(LISTENELEMENT));
```

My Problem is, I dont know how to copy the pointer of the structure and look into it.
memcpy does not work properly... but if I init the variable with the pointer its just a pointer and no copy.

So the target is to create a List of Art and pHead is the pointer of the first LIST. And List includes an ARt and the pointer to the next Art.

Hope anyone can help me creating this construct.

Comment: Are you trying to build a linked list?

Comment: Please tidy up your code. You still have the German names in some places. You also need to form a better understanding of pointers and what they are for. Here, the `next` pointer _points_ to the next element, it doesn't _carry a copy_ of the next element around. The pointers are only the links between existing elements, not the elements themselves. Linked lists are a very popular topic here. I suggest you browse a bit before coding your linked list.

Comment: What exactly does this =>> scanf_s("%d", %art.nr);?   => %

Comment: Your `List` struct is more generally referred to as a `Node` (0 or more `Node`s "linked" by `next` pointers is a linked list).

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the first ART, you make ONE instance of art.  If you want to create more than one, you need to malloc(sizeof(ART)) to get a pointer to the memory to store another instance.